# A special property for Lebesgue measurable sets.

Tags: measure-theory

A defined measure $\mu$ on the Lebesgue measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}^N$ holds the property $\star$ if $\mu(K)<\infty$ for each $K$ compact in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and if exists constant $C>1$ such that
$$
\mu(B[x,2\delta])\leq C\mu(B[x,\delta]), x\in \mathbb{R}^N,\delta>0
$$
Here, $\mu(B[x,\delta])=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^N:|y-x|\leq\delta\}$.

1. The Lebesgue measure $m$ holds $\star$.
2. If $\mu$ holds $\star$ and $\mu\not=0$ so $\mu(\mathbb{R}^N)=\infty$.
3. If $\mu$ holds $\star$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^N$, so $\mu(\{x\})=0$

The item $1$ is easy. I used intervals to cover the balls. The item $2$ is not easy and I have no idea how to solve this.

The item $3$ have a professor's hint: If $v\in\mathbb{R}^N$ with $|v|=1$ we have $\mu(\{x\})+\mu(B[x+\delta v/2,\delta/4])\leq\mu(B[x,\delta])$.

Comment: for 2: in $\mu(\mathbb R^n)=m<\infty$ then for any $epsilon>0$ you'll find $R>0$ such that $\mu(B(0,R))\geq m-\epsilon$ (to see it: $\mathbb R^N$ is the union of $B(0,n)$'s). Now take any $x$ of length $3R$ (say) and consider the balls $B(x,R)$ and $B(x,4R)$ and their measures.

Comment: But what I give with this length $3R$?

Comment: it's just so that $B(0,R)\cap B(x,R)=\emptyset$ and $B(x,4R)\supset B(0,R)$ (choose other number if you prefer :)

Comment: You can't say that "for any $\varepsilon>0$ you'll find $R>0$...". This is say that the supremum of the set measure of balls is $m$, this is true?